# CentOS 7 Live - Read-only file system error

Tags: centos, io, live-usb, readonly

I have loaded a CentOS 7 Gnome Live USB. I wanted to do some operations on it without touching the installed system on the computer, because I only want to try some things.

I installed openssh-server on the Live-USB OS, added a new user and gave him sudo rights.

So I loaded CentOS 7 Gnome Live, downloaded a tar archive (about 500 MB) and wanted to extract this file. But I got this error:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/tar: Input/output error
```

So I tried `touch one`, but I got the error:

```
touch: cannot touch ‘one’: Read-only file system
```

How can I solve this problem? Some hours ago, I started an Ubuntu Live OS, and did the same. There were no problems in downloading any archive, extracting it and installing the software. So why this problem on CentOS?

**Edit**

Maybe useful information: I did nothing on the HDD (I do not know, if the Live OS did something), but I was wary of doing something on the HDD.

**Edit 2**

Looking into `/var/log/messages` shows me a lot of these lines

```
Aug  5 12:51:03 localhost kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-3): ext4_end_bio:332: I/O error -5 writing to inode 262351 (offset 402653184 size 7761920 starting block 1120101)
...
Aug  5 12:51:04 localhost kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 1143313
```

**Edit 3**

Here is maybe some useful output of `dmesg`

```
[68583.204179] Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 1143313
[68583.204187] systemd-journald[941]: /dev/kmsg buffer overrun, some messages lost.
[68585.569969] Aborting journal on device dm-3-8.
[68585.569978] Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 15315
[68585.569980] lost page write due to I/O error on dm-3
[68585.569983] JBD2: Error -5 detected when updating journal superblock for dm-3-8.
[68585.570031] Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 0
[68585.570035] lost page write due to I/O error on dm-3
[68585.570038] EXT4-fs error (device dm-3): ext4_journal_check_start:56: Detected aborted journal
[68585.570042] EXT4-fs (dm-3): Remounting filesystem read-only
[68585.570043] EXT4-fs (dm-3): previous I/O error to superblock detected
[68585.570047] Buffer I/O error on device dm-3, logical block 0
[68585.570048] lost page write due to I/O error on dm-3
```

Answer (score 2):

There should be at least one filesystem mounted read-write. Run `mount` to see all mounted filesystems, and look for one mounted read-write (rw): `mount | grep rw`.

I expect you'll find `/var` mounted read write, and `/var/tmp` and/or `/tmp` should be writeable.

Comment: Yes, I see it. The output of all read-only directories: `/dev/sdc1 on /run/initramfs/live type vfat (ro,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/mapper/live-rw on / type ext4 (ro,noatime,seclabel,data=ordered)`

Comment: I created a subdirectory on `/var/tmp` and wanted to extract the file I downloaded. But I get the same error `-bash: /usr/bin/tar: Input/output error`

Comment: So there are only two filesystems, and both are mounted read-only? I'm not familiar with CentOS Live in particular, but that doesn't sound useful. Lastly, should shouldn't be able to create the subdirectory in /var/tmp/ if that filesystem is read-only. What is your full tar command?

Comment: `tar xvf package.tar`. But I do not think that extracting of a tar archive is the problem. When googling the `Input/Output error`, then some sites say, that this might be of an error of the hard disk. I thought this might be of less ram, but something aroung 16 GB is enough.